# Applying Solver to various rowsa

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I would like to know how I can get code to perform a solver operation on various rows (300 rows). There is one target variable, and several constraints, and two variables that should be optimized. Using the below command, I get an error that the problem is too big for Solver, which can only be a mistake in the syntax. This is my syntax:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 7 To 310

SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AA$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="-0.000001"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AB$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.000001"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AC$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="-0.000001"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AD$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.000001"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AE$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AF$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AE$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AF$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1.5"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i, _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=1000000, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence _
    :=0.0001, StepThru:=True, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
    :=False, RequireBounds:=False, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
    IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
   SolverSolve
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what's the value of `i` when it fails?

Comment: `ByChange:="$AE$:$AF$" & i` - are you sure this is correct ?  Maybe it should be `ByChange:="$AE$" & i & ":$AF$" & i`  Also I think you need to Reset solver after each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is all you need, hanna:

```
Sub hanna()
  Dim i As Long

  For i = 7 To 310
    SolverReset

    With Rows(i)
      SolverOk SetCell:=.Range("AA1").Address, _
               MaxMinVal:=2, _
               ByChange:=.Range("AE1:AF1").Address, _
               Engine:=1
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AA1").Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="-0.000001"
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AB1").Address, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.000001"
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AC1").Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="-0.000001"
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AD1").Address, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.000001"
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AE1").Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
      SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AF1").Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1.5"
      SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I am tempted to downvote this answer... how does this help the OP when they clearly have several different arguments for `Relation` and `FormulaText`?

Comment: My apologies to hanna. I though she was applying the different constraints to the same cell. Edited above.

Comment: If you change all your `1` row references to `i`, I think it would be perfect (qualifying that statement with the fact that I have barely coded the solver function).

Comment: The Rows(i) statement establishes the reference row used by the .Range references.

Comment: After a first test this worked just fine, thank you!